# How do I specify the schema in a URI with psql?

Tags: postgresql, psql

When connecting to a database with `psql` I can specify the database using a URI:

```
psql postgres://user:pass@hostname/my_db
```

But how do I specify the schema?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify it using the `options` query parameter:

```
psql "postgres://user:pass@hostname/my_db?options=--search_path%3Dmy_schema"
```

`%3D` is a URL encoded `=` sign. It has to be URL encoded or `psql` gets confused.